Is it worth reducing Vite build chunk sizes if I am serving compressed files through CloudFront?
Just as the title says, I have a Vite application that is currently building to about 9.5mb, with two index files being the largest offenders. This of course causes the warning to be shown after build that Vite recommends that I attempt to reduce the size.
(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kBs after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application

- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks

- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.

✓ built in x.xxs

I've tried a few different methods that I've found online like adding the built-in splitVendorChunkPlugin to my config file only to find that it actually increased the build size afterward. I also don't want to just silence this warning by modifying the chunckSizeWarningLimit.
Is this problem something worth pursuing further, or is my CloudFront compression doing a good job at mitigating this?
